# Modeling condition, nested forms with elm-simple-forms

Tags: elm

I have a form that starts with a select. Depending on what was selected the form then expands to a common main bit and a details section that depends on the selection.

I started modeling with a separate details section

```
type ProductDetails
    = Book Book.Model
    | Brochure Brochure.Model
    | Card Card.Model

type alias Model =
  { form : Form CustomError Estimate
  , details : ProductDetails      -- a Form CustomerError CardModel / BookModel / ....
  , msg : String
  }
```

but this is becoming quite convoluted to handle in e.g. `view`.

The alternative would seem to be conditionally to add the details into the main form model - e.g.

```
type alias Estimate =
  { customer : String
  , project : String
  , product : String
  , details : ProductDetails
  }
```

Before I get started I’d welcome experience from others on what has worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Dict of the various fields and changed the fields when the product changed. Trying to model each product more explicitly create more boiler plate than I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have separate modules for Book, Brochure and Card? I don't quite understand what is the purpose of your Model but I would structure it like this:

```
import Book
import Brochure
import Card

type Products
    = Book
    | Brochure
    | Card


type Msg
    = Details Products


type alias Model =
    { selectedProduct : Product
    }


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Details prd ->
            Model prd


view : Model -> Html
view model =
    model.selectedProduct.view
```

So as you can see, now you define all available products and then you say that Msg can be Details, which would show details, and it's function would be to set selectedProduct value in Model to selected Product. You can implement selecting with:

```
button [ onClick (Details Book) ] [ text "Book" ]
```

for example to select a book. Later on you want to make it dynamic and the first instinct should be to be able to call the view function of selected Product.

In other case you could define view which would require some fields, which every Product's model would contain and then you could use them to write some information on site.

Please note that code above isn't meant to work, it's just to represent the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `elm-simple-forms`, but this seems like a good representation of your form:

```
type ProductType
  = TBook
  | TBrochure
  | TCard

type Product
  = Book Book.Model
  | Brochure Brochure.Model
  | Card Card.Model

type alias Model =
  { product : Maybe Product
  , customer : String
  , project : String
  }

type Msg
  = SelectProductType ProductType

init : Model
init =
  { product = Nothing
  , customer = ""
  , project = ""
  }

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SelectProductType product ->
      {model | product = 
        case product of
          TBook -> Book Book.init
          TBrochure -> Brochure Brochure.init
          TCard -> Card Card.init
      }

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  case model.product of

    Nothing ->
      myProductTypeSelect

    Just product ->
      withCommonFormInputs
        <| case product of
             Book submodel -> Book.view submodel
             Brochure submodel -> Brochure.view submodel
             Card submodel -> Card.view submodel
```

The `Maybe` gives you a nice way to choose between the first form (just the select) and the second form (customer details + selected product type details).

The `Book.view` etc. give you `Html` which you can add to the common case:

```
withCommonFormInputs : Model -> Html Msg -> Html Msg
withCommonFormInputs model productInputs =
    div
      []
      [ input [] [] -- customer
      , input [] [] -- project
      , productInputs -- product (Book, Brochure, Card) subform
      ]
```